# PHP How to count "subINT" in an array

Tags: php, string, substr

For example, I have an array `[1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5]`
I need to count subINT in this array.
`substr_count();` doesn't work because the values in array isn't string

I need subint function that should return `subint_count($array, 1)` => `2`

Or for example array `[1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6]` should return `subint_count($array, 1)` => `3`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: That's not what I need. I've edited the question. I hope that way it would easy to understand

Comment: What is __subINT__? What's the logic behind all this?

Comment: Does 1 consider subINT of 212?

Comment: `substr_count($array, 1);` doesn't work because the parameter should be string. I need the same function but that accepts integer

Comment: Just use array_count_values. https://3v4l.org/1PT0D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
function subint_count($array, $n) {
    $occurences = 0;
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if ($item == $n) $occurences++;
    } 
    return $occurences;
}

subint([1,2,3,1,1], 1); // returns 3
```

Comment: That's nearly what I need. I added `if ($array[$index] == $n) { $occurences++; }` and I got the function I need. Thanks

Comment: Oh you've edited

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Yep, just edited it.

Comment: You can accept my answer if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function sub_int($array, $n) {
    $count = 0;                               //initialize count
    foreach($array as $val){        //loop through array
        if($val === $n) {                     //check if array element === num Strict comparison. Use == if you don't want strict. 
            $count++;                         //increment count
        }
    }
    return $count; 
}

print_r(sub_int([1,1,3,4,1]));            // should print 3
```